# TextView Background is stretched to fill the entire space of TextView

Tags: android, background, textview

Guys I have a TextView Which is filling the Entire Wdth of the Screen and Height is 300 dp
I have a small Image that should be present at the center of the TextView 
when i use the following code

```
  <TextView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="300dp"
  android:background="@drawable/smallimg"
  >
  </TextView>
```

How to make the Image to maintain its original size and not stretch !

Comment: You should use a relative layout, and add the textview + an imageview inside it. Or even just the textview and set the background of the layout :)

Comment: @Yume117 I also thought of this as a solution but i thought any programatical changes would solve my problem

Comment: Try to create 9-patch with transparent padding and make transparent regions stretched.

Comment: 9-patch is about changing the size and not changing the scaling. Here he doesn't want the size to change since the image is just to be in the center of the text view ?

Comment: So you want a programmatical solution ? 'cause the relative layout one definitly works

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the background fits exactly your TextView size without stretching and that text fits inside, you have to use a 9-patch image or you have to set a fixed size equals to image dimensions.

Comment: No I dont want the Image to Fit the complete size of the TextView it should be be maintaining its original size Like in a ImageView we have sevaral options for scaling the image like fitXY,centercrop,centerinside ..and so on

Comment: The smallimg keeps on changing the image may be bigger than than the textview or smaller than the textview  so I want it to maintain its size if it is smaller than textview and crop if image size is greater than textview